# How to query DBpedia online using SQL?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, semantic-web, wikipedia, dbpedia

DBpedia just released their data as tables, suitable to import into a relational database. How can I query this data online using SQL?

Dataset:
http://wiki.dbpedia.org/DBpediaAsTables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I took the raw data, uploaded it to BigQuery, and made it public. So far I've done it with the 'person' and the 'place' table. Check them at https://bigquery.cloud.google.com/table/fh-bigquery:dbpedia.person.

Now is easy to know what are the most popular alma maters, for example:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), almaMater_label
FROM [fh-bigquery:dbpedia.person]
WHERE almaMater_label != 'NULL'
GROUP BY 2
ORDER BY 1 DESC
```

It's a little more complicated than that, as some people have more than one alma mater - and the particular way DBpedia encodes that. I left the complete query at http://www.reddit.com/r/bigquery/comments/1rjee7/query_wikipedia_in_bigquery_the_dbpedia_dataset/.

Btw, the top alma maters are:

```
   494     Harvard University
   320     University of Cambridge
   314     University of Michigan
   267     Yale University
   216     Trinity College Cambridge
```

You can also do joins between tables.

For example, for each building (from the place table) that has an architect: What year was that architect born? How many buildings with an architect born that year are listed in DBpedia?

```
SELECT COUNT(*), LEFT(b.birthDate, 4) birthYear
FROM [fh-bigquery:dbpedia.place] a
JOIN EACH [fh-bigquery:dbpedia.person] b
ON a.architect = b.URI
WHERE a.architect != 'NULL'
AND birthDate != 'NULL'
GROUP BY 2
ORDER BY 2
```

Results:

```
...
8   1934
13  1935
9   1937
7   1938
17  1939
7   1941
1   1943
15  1944
10  1945
12  1946
7   1947
9   1950
20  1951
1   1952
...
```

*(Google BigQuery has a free monthly quota to query, up to a 100GB each month)
(DBpedia data from version 3.4 on is licensed under the terms of the Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike 3.0 license and the GNU Free Documentation License. http://dbpedia.org/Datasets#h338-24)*